# Generate or write to new JSON file with extjs4

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

How can I generate a JSON file using extjs4?
I have a function that returns a list of strings with `Ext.encode` that looks like this:

```
{"1145":        
    {
     "IN1":15,
     "IN2":6,
     "OUT1 Fix":11,
     "OUT1 Alt":3
     }
}
```

How can I then store it to a JSON file?
I'm using extjs4 with the MVC model, my store now looks like this:

```
Ext.define('M.store.tempGraphData', {
  extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
  model : 'M.model.tempGraphDataModel',
  autoload : true,

  proxy : {
    //I guess this is where I should put something to write to my json file?
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: `ExtJS 4` is javascript my friend, the only access it has to is this: http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/ which is HTML 5, and is not ready for primetime yet, you'd have to post this json to a server and may be the server can write it as a file. you most certainly cannot create a file by just using `ExtJS`

Comment: As Soman said, javascript cannot write files the client's file system for security purposes. But I have a feeling this is not what you meant. Could you please elaborate what exactly you are trying to do?